# Angular unit test for a service with constants using Jasmine

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I have the following service with a constant:

```
angular.module('app',[]).constant('alertType',{
  success:1,
  error:0  
})
.factory("dataService",dataService);

dataService.$inject = ['$timeout', 'alertType']

function dataService($timeout, alertType) {
    return {
        //some code related to the service
    } 
}
```

Here is the test case for the service to check if it is registered or not

```
describe('Testing "dataService" service', function() {
  var _dataService;

  beforeEach(function() {
    module('app');

    inject(function(dataService) {
      _dataService = dataService;
    });
  });
  it('Should be registered', function() {
    expect(_dataService).toBeDefined();
  });
});
```

For some reason it doesn't work. I get a very long error that looks something like this:

> Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: dataServiceProvider <- dataService  http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.0/$injector/unpr?p0=dataServiceProvider%20%3C-%20dataService

Am I doing it right or is there anything wrong with this?

Comment: Please define *"it doesn't work"*

Comment: @Phil added the error description that I am getting

Comment: The error says something about being unable to instantiate the module `angularBootstrapNavTree` due to a further *"nomod"* error but the rest is truncated. You should switch to using the un-minified version of `angular.js` while developing as the error messages are more verbose

Comment: mke sure in your karma file you include all the files needed to bootstrap your application ui-bootstrap included

Comment: Thank you for that. That error is now resolved. Now I am getting something like Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: dataServiceProvider <- dataService
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.0/$injector/unpr?p0=dataServiceProvider%20%3C-%20dataService

Comment: It seems that you did not include the source file into the Karma config file. Put a `console.log` in the source file to check whether it is included or not

Comment: @AlexanderElgin I double checked that file. I have included it in karma.conf.js

Comment: @BiJ Do you see the output of `console.log` that you put in the source file once you run the test suite?

Answer (score 0):

Try mocking your provider at the top of your describe block like so:

```
beforeEach(module($provide => {
 $provide.constant('alertType',{
      success: 1,
      error: 0
   });
}));
```

For more details please refer to this answer: [Unknown Provider when unit testing filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28726984/unknown-provider-when-unit-testing-filter)